# WPF DataGrid changing a button text depending on a value

Tags: wpf, image, datagrid, button

I would like to have the text on the button changed when the value of the variable is changing.
For example: value of the var is 0 (turned off), so button should display text "turn on"; if the var value is 1 the button should display "turn off".
I would like also to display an image in another column depending on the value of this variable.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), you can add another property on your ViewModel that returns either "turn on" or "turn off", implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) to tell the binding system when its value changes, and bind your button's Content to it:

```
<Button Content="{Binding ButtonText}"/>
```

If you're not using MVVM, you'll need to write a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx). But you'll still need your backing object to implement INotifyPropertyChanged -- otherwise the button will never know that the Boolean value changed, so it will never update its text. So I would probably recommend the ViewModel approach instead of the value converter.